# How to remove a row in SSIS when a value is not a date

Tags: ssis

I have a massive excel spreadsheet I'm trying to port over to a database via SSIS.  There are some rows that don't have a date value and I don't them moved over (they are group headers and total lines).  I'm using a conditional split to handle those, but I don't know an expression that will discard those rows.  Can I do such a thing?

EDIT: When I say the date column doesn't have a date value, I meant that there's a value there that is not a date.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only difference between the records is the empty date value then the SSIS expression could be LEN(DateCol)>0?1:0 So if it outputs 1 you take the data downstream on the split.

Comment: I wasn't clear when I wrote the question.  There is a value in the date column for the rows with totals, it just isn't a date value.

Comment: That complicates the validation part. I thus suggest you stage the data from Excel 1st then do removal of extra records by the T-SQL facilities e.g. SQL Server 2012 and onward has the TRY_PARSE clause you can use like SELECT TRY_PARSE('GIBBERISH' AS date USING 'en-US') AS DateMayBe;

Comment: I am new to SSIS, so I am unclear on what you mean by stage the data.  Is there an intermediary step I am missing?

Comment: "stage the data" means import it, as is, to a "staging" table in sql server.  Since you won't be cleansing the data first, you would import everything into varchar columns.   Then use sql to get rid of the rows that don't pass your validation tests, whatever they may be, and import the rest to your current destination table.

Comment: Ok.  Sounds like a plan.